# How can I add new sheets to the file im opening instead of the personal macro workbook?

Tags: excel, vba

My first task every morning is to grab two files that are generated by another department. I then essentially "move" information around within the file to prepare for emails. One of the things that must be done is to have the addition of new sheets in which I was able to write a macro for and add it to the personal macro workbook. The issue that I'm running into however is that whenever new sheets are added, the macro will add them to the personal macro workbook instead of the file that I open every morning and need the sheets added to.

I believe this is in part to the section of the code (Below) that adds the sheets, however i am not sure what to use in place of this. Can someone please assist? Thanks

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add.Name = "PAV"       ' This adds three new sheets
ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add.Name = "PAS"
ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add.Name = "PAD"
```

Below is the entire macro:

```
Sub PaidAgainst()
Dim Cll As Range
Dim myrange As Range
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set myrange = Application.Union(Range("E2", Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)), Range("S2", Range("S" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)))

On Error GoTo EH

ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add.Name = "PAV"       ' This adds three new sheets
ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add.Name = "PAS"
ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add.Name = "PAD"



For Each Cll In myrange
    If Len(Cll) < 2 Then
    
        Cll.Offset(1, 0).Copy
        Cll.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    
    End If
Next Cll


Sheet1.Select
Columns("J:J").Select
    Selection.Cut
Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.Insert shift:=xlToRight


Range("D1").Select                                                          ' This adds a filter and selects "BAI" values only
  Selection.AutoFilter
  ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$S$7").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="BAI"

Sheet1.Activate
Sheet1.Range("$A$1:$S$46").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
"Paid against dormant"

Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy
Worksheets("PAD").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.PasteSpecial

Sheet1.Range("$A$1:$S$46").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
"Paid against stop"

Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Resize(, 14).Copy
Worksheets("PAS").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Resize(, 14).PasteSpecial


Sheet1.Range("$A$1:$S$46").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
"Paid against void"

Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Resize(, 14).Copy
Worksheets("PAV").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Resize(, 14).PasteSpecial



Exit Sub
EH:
MsgBox "An error occured"


Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```

Comment: Use `ActiveWorkbook` instead of `ThisWorkbook`.

Comment: You'll also have to change the instances of `Sheet1` further down, probably to `Worksheets(1)`.

Comment: I changed the instances as well as that fixed the other issues I had. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `ThisWorkbook` refers to the workbook where the code is actually running from, in your case, your personal macro workbook.

Change the code to refer to `ActiveWorkbook`, which addresses the workbook that is currently in the active window.

Best would be to create a proper workbook variable and use that to reference workbooks and sheets within workbooks without any doubt.

```
dim wb as Workbook
set wb = ActiveWorkbook
[...] ' later in the code
wb.Worksheets("PAD").Range[...]
[...]
wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("[...]
```

Comment: This fixed it perfectly! Thanks